# libcurl ignores http_proxy when run through gdb

Tags: c, gdb, libcurl

I run my application like this

```
http_proxy=http://myrpoxy foo=foo gdb --ex "run"  ./app
```

I can confirm from within the app that i sees the environment variables. However using curlopt_verbose I can see that curl ignores the `http_proxy` variable. It does not when I run without gdb and, as I've just said, I can print correct value from within the app. Why can this happen?

Comment: Can you see `http_proxy` in `(gdb) show environment`?

Comment: @273K yes I can.

Comment: If you see the proxy in the dump, then the proxy may not be ignored.

Comment: I also think so. But it is.